# Tensorflow distributed training hangs with RecvTensor cancelled warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I'm training a model using tensorflow 2.1.0's estimator api under parameter server distributed mode. The code to launch the training is like this:

```
# model_fn is defined with model logit
GATNE = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=args.model_dir, params=model_params, config=config)

# obtain different train and eval files for different workers
# files are stored on shared hdfs
train_files, eval_files = get_files_for_worker()

# the input_fn is going to raises an end-of-input exception after epochs
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
            input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train_files, batch_size=args.batch_size, num_epochs=args.epochs),
            max_steps=None)

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
            input_fn=lambda: input_fn(eval_files, batch_size=args.batch_size, num_epochs=1),
            steps=1000,
            exporters=exporter,
            throttle_secs=300)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(GATNE, train_spec, eval_spec)

print("Done.")
```

I'm using 2 ps servers and 5 workers (index ranges from 0 to 4) the train the model. Worker 0 is chief while worker 1 is the evaluator and the rests are ordinary workers.

After the training task is launched, **worker 4 finished the training task successfully**, here is some of the logs of this worker (I add some log information during training like `******************* [2021-04-01 12:05] global_step: 4331 *************************` to track the steps):

```
..............
2021-04-01 12:05:13.483 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:05] global_step: 4331 *************************
2021-04-01 12:05:55.315 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:05] global_step: 4535 *************************
2021-04-01 12:06:40.621 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:06] global_step: 4733 *************************
2021-04-01 12:07:30.341 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:07] global_step: 4936 *************************
2021-04-01 12:08:16.981 INFO:tensorflow:loss = 59.152977, step = 5136 (434.022 sec)
2021-04-01 12:08:16.981 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:08] global_step: 5136 *************************
2021-04-01 12:09:04.206 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:09] global_step: 5337 *************************
2021-04-01 12:09:51.85 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:09] global_step: 5537 *************************
2021-04-01 12:10:38.679 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:10] global_step: 5742 *************************
2021-04-01 12:11:25.781 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:11] global_step: 5948 *************************
2021-04-01 12:12:07.822 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:12] global_step: 6123 *************************
2021-04-01 12:12:54.258 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:12] global_step: 6327 *************************
2021-04-01 12:13:41.683 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:13] global_step: 6528 *************************
2021-04-01 12:14:21.60 INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 62.46709.
2021-04-01 12:14:21.60 Done.
```

However, all other workers get a warning of: `W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842` and hangs forever.

Some of the logs of worker 2:

```
......
2021-04-01 12:11:14.380 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:11] global_step: 5899 *************************
2021-04-01 12:11:56.730 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:11] global_step: 6077 *************************
2021-04-01 12:12:39.956 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:12] global_step: 6269 *************************
2021-04-01 12:13:26.957 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:13] global_step: 6468 *************************
2021-04-01 12:14:14.77 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:14] global_step: 6668 *************************
2021-04-01 12:14:50.611 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:14] global_step: 6821 *************************
2021-04-01 12:15:19.129 2021-04-01 12:15:19.128988: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.129 2021-04-01 12:15:19.129495: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.132 2021-04-01 12:15:19.132203: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.132 2021-04-01 12:15:19.132261: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.132 2021-04-01 12:15:19.132339: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.132 2021-04-01 12:15:19.132388: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
```

And worker 3:

```
2021-04-01 12:14:22.586 INFO:tensorflow:loss = 60.513123, step = 6703 (462.406 sec)
2021-04-01 12:14:22.586 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:14] global_step: 6703 *************************
2021-04-01 12:14:58.652 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:14] global_step: 6855 *************************
2021-04-01 12:15:30.105 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:15] global_step: 6984 *************************
2021-04-01 12:15:53.527 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:15] global_step: 7084 *************************
2021-04-01 12:16:17.568 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:16] global_step: 7184 *************************
2021-04-01 12:16:41.582 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:16] global_step: 7284 *************************
2021-04-01 12:17:05.140 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:17] global_step: 7384 *************************
2021-04-01 12:17:22.976 INFO:tensorflow:******************* [2021-04-01 12:17] global_step: 7485 *************************
2021-04-01 12:17:36.575 2021-04-01 12:17:36.574901: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
```

These worker just hangs and I don't know why. From the ps server log, there are also some similar warnings:

ps server 0:

```
2021-04-01 11:48:01.233 2021-04-01 11:48:01.232972: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:390] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
2021-04-01 12:14:20.957 2021-04-01 12:14:20.957449: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
2021-04-01 12:15:19.133 2021-04-01 12:15:19.132949: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.133 2021-04-01 12:15:19.133103: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.133 2021-04-01 12:15:19.133120: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.133 2021-04-01 12:15:19.133131: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.133 2021-04-01 12:15:19.133141: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.133 2021-04-01 12:15:19.133151: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.133 2021-04-01 12:15:19.133174: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
2021-04-01 12:17:35.837 2021-04-01 12:17:35.836897: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577149: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577221: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577233: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577312: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577323: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577330: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577339: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577348: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577355: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577363: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.577 2021-04-01 12:17:36.577369: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.579 2021-04-01 12:17:36.579436: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
```

ps server 1:

```
2021-04-01 11:46:28.368 2021-04-01 11:46:28.368034: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:390] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
2021-04-01 12:14:20.955 2021-04-01 12:14:20.955100: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 42171233248859519
2021-04-01 12:14:20.958 2021-04-01 12:14:20.957943: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
2021-04-01 12:15:19.130 2021-04-01 12:15:19.130513: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.130 2021-04-01 12:15:19.130639: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.130 2021-04-01 12:15:19.130660: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.130 2021-04-01 12:15:19.130680: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
2021-04-01 12:15:19.134 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134413: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.134 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134734: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.134 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134767: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.134 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134853: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134870: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134908: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134976: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.134993: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.135043: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.135084: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.135120: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.135133: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.135177: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:15:19.135 2021-04-01 12:15:19.135212: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 44977866739330842
2021-04-01 12:17:35.837 2021-04-01 12:17:35.837269: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
2021-04-01 12:17:36.578 2021-04-01 12:17:36.578073: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.578 2021-04-01 12:17:36.578184: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.578 2021-04-01 12:17:36.578216: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc:510] RecvTensor cancelled for 48095428538436363
2021-04-01 12:17:36.580 2021-04-01 12:17:36.580204: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/worker.cc:204] Cancellation requested for RunGraph.
```

The log for chief and evaluator looks fine. I googled the `RecvTensor cancelled` warning and can't find enough information about it. Maybe this is a network problem? But this warning always shows up and workers are hanged each time I launched the training task. So I guess this is not occasionally.

I've tried a few times and found that there will always be one worker that finishes successfully and right after that, other workers will hang.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my task a few times and found that one training worker will finish at the first place, then all the other training workers starts to hang. So I guess the finished training worker has some impact to the other workers. How about let the first finished training worker not "finished"? So I added a 10-minutes sleep after the training code for each training worker in order to let the worker not "finished". And this worked. While the first finished worker is sleeping, other training workers keeps training properly and all finished training within 10-minutes. This is my solution so far. Still open to other solutions.